# redirect using the rewriteengine from one folder to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like it so that when you go to localhost/home it sends you to localhost/public.

this is what I have so far :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on    
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using : `RewriteRule ^home/(.*) http://localhost/public/$1 [R=301,L]`